# TypeError: this.state.patients.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, mern

i am new in react js,and i am learning to create a React application and I got a problem with mapping function:

Here's my request and how I am attempting to render the data:

```js
class Patients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      patients: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    api.getPatients()
      .then( patients => {
        console.log( patients)
        this.setState({
          patients:  patients
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
  render() {                
    return (
      <div className=" Patientss">
        <h2>List of Patient</h2>
        {this.state.patients.map((c, i) => <li key={i}>{c.name}</li>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Patients;
```

here my api calling

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/api' : 'http://localhost:3000/patient',
});

const errHandler = err => {
  console.error(err);
  throw err;
};

export default {
    service: service,
    
    getPatients() {
      return service
        .get('/')
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(errHandler);
    },
    }
```

and I get the following error:
`TypeError: this.state.patients.map is not a function`

i've try to use slice aswell but it didnt work, anyone know whats wrong with my code?`

Comment: Are you sure you have data inside server response?
Can you show us what this console.log( patients) give?

Comment: `{…}`
​
`count: 24`
​
`patient: Array(24) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]`
​
`<prototype>: Object { … }`

Comment: @RiaAnggraini its an object, use `patients.patient` in setState.

Comment: @MayankShukla yeah thats true, thanks, i did stupid mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the symptoms (heh), the `patients` object you get in `api.getPatients()` isn't an array.

`console.log()` it to see what it actually is.

EDIT: Based on the comments, the `patients` object looks like

```
{
  count: 24,
  patient: [...],
}
```

so the `this.setState()` call needs to be

```
this.setState({patients: patients.patient})
```

Comment: here the console result `{…}`
​
`count: 24`
​
`patient: Array(24) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]`
​
`<prototype>: Object { … }`

Comment: @RiaAnggraini Okay. Updated my answer with a solution based on that.

Comment: its works, thankyou a lot ,i ve been lookin for the problem since this morning , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this as an conditional rendering. It will check that if this.state.patient exists then only it will go ahead and call this.state.patients.map function. It will also ensure that you don't receive any errors later on due to bad responses.

I updated your Patients Code example.

```
class Patients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      patients: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    api.getPatients()
      .then( patients => {
        console.log( patients)
        this.setState({
          patients:  patients
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
  render() {                
    return (
      <div className=" Patientss">
        <h2>List of Patient</h2>
        { this.state.patients && this.state.patients.map((c, i) => <li key={i}>{c.name}</li>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Patients;
```

I hope it helps. Thanks!!