# TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function when setting state to a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I get the following error when  mapping the state for my `posts:[]` object

> TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function

I looked at something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534747/typeerror-this-state-patients-map-is-not-a-function) but it didn't come close to resolving the problem.

The console.log() shows the current data, so the function works, it just a matter of passing the data within the `posts:[]` object and mapping it.

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, key)=> {
    return(
        <div key={key}>
            <h2>{post.description}</h2>

            <small>{post.username}</small>

        </div>
    ); 
})}
```

**Dashboard.js** (updated)

```
class Dashboard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username:"",
            loading: true,
            posts:{},
            myArray:[]
        }

    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getPosts()
    }

    getPosts() {
        const collection2 = fire.collection('posts');
        collection2.get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => { 
                let items = doc.data();
                // items = JSON.stringify(items);
                this.setState({
                  posts: items
                });
            })    
        const eArray = Object.values(this.state.posts);
        this.setState({
            myArray:[...eArray]
        })

        console.log(this.state.myArray)
        })


    }


    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.userId){
            const collection = fire.collection('users');
            collection.get().then(snapshot => {     
              snapshot.forEach(doc => { 
                this.setState({
                    username: doc.data().username,
                    loading:false
                })                 
              });   
            });

        }

    }

    render(){
        if (!this.props.userId) return <Redirect to='/' />
        const { loading, posts,myArray } = this.state;

        if(loading){
           return(
            <div className="loader"></div>
           ) 
        }
        return(
            <div className="container"> 
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-3">
                        <h1>Welcome {this.state.username.toLowerCase()}</h1>

                        {myArray.map((post, key)=> {
                            return(
                                <div key={key}>
                                    <h2>{post.description}</h2>

                                    <small>{post.username}</small>


                                </div>
                            ); 
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        );
    }


}
```

Comment: when you `console.log(this.state.posts)` is it an array?

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez `{ }` with data about the post information, it's in object not array

Comment: You can't use `.map` on an Object. [More info about Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: i sorta figured it out, the code is a little bit better, but it just a matter of get the elements to show. I'll update the code so u can see what i have now.

Comment: it looks somewhat hacky imo, i pass the objects within an array now. I see a console.log with data but there is an issue that is not allowing it to show it on the page.

Comment: You shouldn't call `this.setState` in a loop. Instead, save the data an `someArray` and push `someArray.push(doc.data())` each item. Then call `this.setState` once after the loop.

Comment: can u show an example with the existing code, im kinda confused.

Comment: this is what i have now `collection2.get().then(snapshot => {
                this.setState({
                    posts:snapshot.data()
                })
            })`

Comment: just getting  `snapshot.data is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you're getting in the console is because you're using `.map` on an Object, but map is a method of Array. [More info on .map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

There's also another problem with your code and is that you shouldn't call `this.setState` inside a loop. Instead, collect the data you need from the loop and then update the `state`.

Something like this

```
      getPosts() {
        const collection2 = fire.collection('posts');
        collection2.get().then(snapshot => {
            let arr = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => { 
              arr.push(doc.data()); //Collect all the items and push it into the array
            })
            this.setState({
              posts: arr,
            })
        })
    }
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do on `componentDidMount`. But this should point you in the right direction and solve the error that you're experiencing with `map` not being a function.

Comment: it worked thank you so much i delete the `eArray` and the other code. It works, and i understand your logic behind this.

Comment: Glad to help Jasmine!

Answer (score 0):

You setting state in forEach loop. You just set last element of collection2.get() result to `state.posts` which makes forEach loop meaningless. There is no difference

```
   collection2.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.setState({
                posts: doc.data()
            })
        })
        console.log(this.state.posts)
    })
```

with

```
   collection2.get().then(snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                posts: snapshot[snapshot.length - 1].doc.data()
            })
    })
```

setState asynchronous and will conflict with the different states available on each iteration in that forEach () loop.

Comment: i get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined`

Comment: im trying some variations when removing the doc `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`